# How we get Uninstallation App Cancel event in an android

Tags: android

I have problem in App Uninstallation. My Application Need is When user want to do application uninstall then open a login screen. when user press your right Password then show a Uninstall  App System Alert. And That Alert Have two condition (1) OK
(2) cancel. when user click "OK" then app uninstall correctly. When App Uninstalled Correctly them get a BroadcastReciver Like "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" . if User click a Cancel Button "How we get Any BroadcastReciver Or Notification in an android".

public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
/**
 * This method captures the event when a package has been removed
 */
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    System.out.println("Hello from CustomBroadcastReceiver");
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();   
        System.out.println("L1123 : "+action);
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"))
        {
            SMContants.Removed_Apps=true;
            //Log the event capture in the log file ...
            SMContants.App_uninstalled=false;          /// Important Line
            System.out.println("The package has been removed");
        }

        else
        {
            SMContants.App_uninstalled=false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

when I am Write a Important Line

I want when user click on Cancel Button then value of Variable

SMContants.App_uninstalled=false;

**How we Get the App Uninstallation Cancel Button Event**

Comment: "How we Get the App Uninstallation Cancel Button Event" -- you don't. There is no supported means to interfere with the uninstallation process, and any unsupported means would imply a security flaw.